# Pass data from one page to another after button click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to pass multiple data from one page to another on event button click.I ask this because i need to generate a report for my html page from the form that i search from database i need to create a separate html that i can print like how you print `.doc files`.

Questions:

1. Pass data (many) from one page to another after button click
2. Print the html page just like how you print `.doc files`

Comment: Is it a requirement that there is no server-side script?  If yes, then take a look at cookies, or LocalStorage, or IndexedDB, depending which browsers must be supported and amount of data.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have 2 pages (let's say html pages). Page 1 has search functionality and upon the search button click, the page 2 has to be displayed with the data and it should have the ability to print. Am I correct?

Comment: @Vim from page 1 i will search for data in database them put them in input boxes. then when all the input are generated i can show the button(hidden when input is not complete) then when this button is clicked i go to the next page(page 2) where i position the data in a way that they will look like a report then print that page

Comment: @Jonathan from page 1 to page 2 i think i dont need to make server side scripting anymore because i already dont the server things needed before hand in page 1